# bring back to original position if not dropped to target point using animation in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have made the functionality of drag and drop using ondraglistener. Its working fine But my problem is that when it is not dropped to target point it should come back to its original position using animation.So that user see it correctly that is not dropped to right position. Any help ? 
Thanks in advance.